# outputs the number of pixels for each color in the image using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

**I need to output the number of pixels from an image**

Hello guys, I need a hand to output the total number of pixels by color. I am new to image processing with Numpy and Numpy array. I know  I need to have knowledge of it when I am dealing with individual pixel in image. I try to look for more resources about obtaining pixels value with Numpy. I couldn't find any helpful to my situation.Please help me. I am eager to learn more. Any documentation or blog post or books. Any comments highly appreciated.

I am trying to print like this:

```
      red   :   ????? pixels
      green : ??????? pixels
      blue  :     ??? pixels
    -------------------------
```

the image shape is (1536, 2048, 3)

I have tried this code

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
img_path = "sample.png"
with Image.open(img_path) as im:
    data = np.array(im)
    red, green, blue = data[:, :, 0], data[:, :, 1], data[:, :, 2]
    print(red, green, blue)
```

But it given me something like this

```
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]] [[255 255 255 ... 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ... 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ... 255 255 255]
 ...
 [255 255 255 ... 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ... 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ... 255 255 255]] [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this at the end.

```
print(np.count_nonzero(red))
print(np.count_nonzero(green))
print(np.count_nonzero(blue))
```

EDIT:

If you don't use single channel colors you could do something like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
img_path = "sample.png"

colors = {}
with Image.open(img_path) as im:
    data = np.array(im)
    for row in data:
        for pixel in row:
            color = '{}_{}_{}'.format(*pixel)
            colors[color] = colors.get(color, 0)
            colors[color] += 1

for color, count in colors.items():
    print(color, count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.count_nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html), reducing along the two first axes, which will give you a count of pixels across the channels:

```
np.count_nonzero(im, axis=(0,1))
```

For instance:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_images
im = load_sample_images()['images'][0]
np.count_nonzero(im, axis=(0,1))
# array([272366, 272418, 268717], dtype=int64)
```